# How to install divisi2 with python 2.7?

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to install `divisi2` on Anaconda python 2.7.
I've tried each and every method I know: `pip`, `easy_install`, from python source, but it won't install.

An example output given below. I know the listing is long, but please forgive me as a new user. Please help.

```
pip install divisi2
==================

Collecting divisi2   Using cached Divisi2-2.2.5.tar.gz Requirement
already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): csc-utils>=0.6.1 in
c:\anaconda\lib\site-packages (from divisi2) Requirement already
satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): networkx in
c:\anaconda\lib\site-packages (from divisi2) Requirement already
satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): csc-pysparse in
c:\anaconda\lib\site-packages (from divisi2) Installing collected
packages: divisi2   Running setup.py install for divisi2
    Complete output from command C:\Anaconda\python.exe -c "import setuptools,
tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\prabha~1\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-unmliw\\divisi2\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize,
'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__,
'exec'))" install --record
c:\users\prabha~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-5kcj45-record\install-record.txt
--single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-2.7
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\divisi2
    copying divisi2\blending.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\divisi2
    copying divisi2\ccipca.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\divisi2
    copying divisi2\dataset.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\divisi2
    copying divisi2\dense.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\divisi2
    copying divisi2\examples.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\divisi2
    copying divisi2\exceptions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\divisi2
    copying divisi2\export_svdview.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\divisi2
    copying divisi2\fileIO.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\divisi2
    copying divisi2\labels.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\divisi2
    copying divisi2\network.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\divisi2
    copying divisi2\operators.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\divisi2
    copying divisi2\ordered_set.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\divisi2
    copying divisi2\priodict.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\divisi2
    copying divisi2\reconstructed.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\divisi2
    copying divisi2\sparse.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\divisi2
    copying divisi2\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\divisi2
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\divisi2\algorithms
    copying divisi2\algorithms\mds.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\divisi2\algorithms
    copying divisi2\algorithms\nmf.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\divisi2\algorithms
    copying divisi2\algorithms\randomized_svd.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\divisi2\algorithms
    copying divisi2\algorithms\svd.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\divisi2\algorithms
    copying divisi2\algorithms\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\divisi2\algorithms
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\divisi2\test
    copying divisi2\test\ordercompare.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\divisi2\test
    copying divisi2\test\test_dense.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\divisi2\test
    copying divisi2\test\test_pickle.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\divisi2\test
    copying divisi2\test\test_priodict.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\divisi2\test
    copying divisi2\test\test_sparse.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\divisi2\test
    copying divisi2\test\test_svd.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\divisi2\test
    copying divisi2\test\test_tfidf.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\divisi2\test
    copying divisi2\test\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\divisi2\test
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\divisi2\test\eval
    copying divisi2\test\eval\test_predictions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\divisi2\test\eval
    copying divisi2\test\eval\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\divisi2\test\eval
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\divisi2\data
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\divisi2\data\graphs
    copying divisi2\data\graphs\conceptnet_en.graph.gz -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\divisi2\data\graphs
    copying divisi2\data\graphs\conceptnet_ja.graph.gz -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\divisi2\data\graphs
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\divisi2\data\eval
    copying divisi2\data\eval\usertest_data.pickle -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\divisi2\data\eval
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\divisi2\data\matrices
    copying divisi2\data\matrices\conceptnet_assoc_en.gz -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\divisi2\data\matrices
    copying divisi2\data\matrices\conceptnet_assoc_ja.gz -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\divisi2\data\matrices
    copying divisi2\data\matrices\conceptnet_en.gz -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\divisi2\data\matrices
    copying divisi2\data\matrices\conceptnet_ja.gz -> build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\divisi2\data\matrices
    running build_ext
    building 'divisi2._svdlib' extension
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\svdlib
    c:\mingw\bin\gcc.exe -DMS_WIN64 -mdll -O -Wall -IC:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -Isvdlib -IC:\Anaconda\include -IC:\Anaconda\PC -c svdlib/_svdlib.c -o build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\svdlib\_svdlib.o -g
    In file included from C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h:1804:0,
                     from C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:17,
                     from C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include/numpy/arrayobject.h:4,
                     from svdlib/_svdlib.c:237:
    C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include/numpy/npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h:12:9:
note: #pragma message:
C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include/numpy/npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h(12)
: Warning Msg: Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by #defining
NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION
     #pragma message(_WARN___LOC__"Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by " \
             ^
    svdlib/_svdlib.c: In function '__pyx_f_6svdlib_7_svdlib_llmat_to_smat_shifted':
    svdlib/_svdlib.c:1310:14: warning: variable '__pyx_bshape_0_col_mapping' set but not used
[-Wunused-but-set-variable]
       Py_ssize_t __pyx_bshape_0_col_mapping = 0;
                  ^
    svdlib/_svdlib.c:1309:14: warning: variable '__pyx_bstride_0_col_mapping' set but not used
[-Wunused-but-set-variable]
       Py_ssize_t __pyx_bstride_0_col_mapping = 0;
                  ^
..........................
............................
.....................................

    C:/Anaconda/lib/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/__multiarray_api.h:1636:
undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_ImportError'
    C:/Anaconda/lib/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/__multiarray_api.h:1636:
undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_SetString'
    C:/Anaconda/lib/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/__multiarray_api.h:1639:
undefined reference to `_imp__PyObject_GetAttrString'
    C:/Anaconda/lib/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/__multiarray_api.h:1642:
undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_AttributeError'
    C:/Anaconda/lib/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/__multiarray_api.h:1642:
undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_SetString'
    C:/Anaconda/lib/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/__multiarray_api.h:1654:
undefined reference to `_imp__PyCObject_Type'
    C:/Anaconda/lib/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/__multiarray_api.h:1655:
undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_RuntimeError'
    C:/Anaconda/lib/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/__multiarray_api.h:1655:
undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_SetString'
    C:/Anaconda/lib/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/__multiarray_api.h:1659:
undefined reference to `_imp__PyCObject_AsVoidPtr'
    C:/Anaconda/lib/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/__multiarray_api.h:1663:
undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_RuntimeError'
    C:/Anaconda/lib/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/__multiarray_api.h:1663:
undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_SetString'
    C:/Anaconda/lib/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/__multiarray_api.h:1669:
undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_RuntimeError'
    C:/Anaconda/lib/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/__multiarray_api.h:1669:
undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_Format'
    C:/Anaconda/lib/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/__multiarray_api.h:1675:
undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_RuntimeError'
    C:/Anaconda/lib/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/__multiarray_api.h:1675:
undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_Format'
    C:/Anaconda/lib/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/__multiarray_api.h:1687:
undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_RuntimeError'
    C:/Anaconda/lib/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/__multiarray_api.h:1687:
undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_Format'
    C:/Anaconda/lib/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/__multiarray_api.h:1698:
undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_RuntimeError'
    C:/Anaconda/lib/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/__multiarray_api.h:1698:
undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_Format'
    build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\svdlib\svdwrapper.o: In function `init_numpy':
    c:\users\prabha~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-unmliw\divisi2/svdlib/svdwrapper.c:67:
undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_Print'
    c:\users\prabha~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-unmliw\divisi2/svdlib/svdwrapper.c:67:
undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_ImportError'
    c:\users\prabha~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-unmliw\divisi2/svdlib/svdwrapper.c:67:
undefined reference to `_imp__PyErr_SetString'
    build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\svdlib\svdwrapper.o: In function `wrapSVDrec':
    c:\users\prabha~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-unmliw\divisi2/svdlib/svdwrapper.c:105:
undefined reference to `_imp__PyTuple_New'
    c:\users\prabha~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-unmliw\divisi2/svdlib/svdwrapper.c:106:
undefined reference to `_imp__PyTuple_SetItem'
    c:\users\prabha~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-unmliw\divisi2/svdlib/svdwrapper.c:108:
undefined reference to `_imp__PyTuple_SetItem'
    c:\users\prabha~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-unmliw\divisi2/svdlib/svdwrapper.c:111:
undefined reference to `_imp__PyTuple_SetItem'
    collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    error: command 'c:\\mingw\\bin\\gcc.exe' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
```

Comment: The `divisi2` module was written between 3 and 5 years ago, some things may have broken with the last numpy releases (particularly in the Numpy C-API). You could try raising this issue with the developers on github.

Answer (score 0):

Generally the easiest way to install a package in Anaconda (if you can find it there) is through binstar.org. I looked up your package through binstar and found this command (which worked just fine to install):

```
    pip install -i https://pypi.binstar.org/pypi/simple divisi2
```

Comment: It seems to be working, but I am getting other errors, probably not related to the original problem. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, its not working still. It gives a lot of "undefined references" now.

Comment: Is this during installation or after?

Comment: Its during installation, I have tried both MinGW (32, 64) as well as MSVC++

Comment: I am out of options, can't find any solution. The followings I have done: